# QGIS Virtual layer with collected (multi-part geometry)

Tags: qgis, sql

I have a layer that will be changing so I don't want to dissolve it and would prefer to make a virtual multi-part layer if that's possible?

I can use a geometry generator to collect the features into groups as I would like for display purposes but doesn't solve my issues for labelling.

```
collect( $geometry, group_by:= "GDTree No")
```

I can create a virtual layer using SQL

```
select* from mysinglepartlayer
```

Is there an SQL equivalent to the collect function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```sql
select st_collect(mysinglepartlayer.geometry) as geometry, -- put here the fields to retain or use * to retain all
from mysinglepartlayer
group by "GDTree No"
```

Remember to set the right name for the input geometry column name in `st_collect(<geometry column name here>)`. Read [here](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Collect.html) how to use `st_collect` as an aggregate.